# How to get the epoch anchor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rust

I'm trying to mimmick a temporal API from thee TC39 proposal in Rust and have two internal implementations: one that uses the standard library and one that uses JavaScript (for the browser). It hides other dependencies that might make life easier when mimmicking the proposal.

I'm trying to implement the `Instant` type and mimmick [`new Temporal.Instant(epochNanoseconds)`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/instant.html#new-Temporal-Instant) as `temporal::Instant::from_epoch()`, but for one case, I'm using `SystemTime` from Rust inside my `Instant` (which doesn't work in the browser), and for the browser case, I'm using epoch milliseconds inside (`Date.now()` for instance returns epoch milliseconds).

For non-browser platforms, I can add the given epoch duration to `std::time::SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH`, but I found nothing similiar to that for the browser. Do I've to use a constant myself then?

Comment: In JavaScript `new Date(0)` is the anchor date. You can pass epoch milliseconds as argument, so 0 gives you the anchor. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @trincot Right, I think I misunderstood something in that "anchor". I thought it were something other than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript uses milliseconds, but looks like this temporal uses nanoseconds so all we need to do is divide by 1000000.

Now nanoseconds as time is not going to fit into Javascript Number, so we need to use BigInts for this.

Below is an example.

```js
const turnOfTheCentury = -2208988800000000000n;

function convertToMsTime(t) {
  return Number(t / 1000000n);
}

console.log(new Date(convertToMsTime(turnOfTheCentury)));
```

Comment: I'm going to take the duration as `Duration` that converts to units, so no issues. I thought there was something special though with "anchor" (as @trincot said, it's just zero, so I was fooled)

Answer (score 1):

The [std::time::UNIX_EPOCH](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/constant.UNIX_EPOCH.html) constant of Rust, is just 0 in JavaScript -- you pass it as argument to the Date constructor to get it as a Date object:

```
new Date(0)
```

Pass any other number of milliseconds as argument to get an offset from that anchor date (positive or negative). See mdn docs on the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date), specifically the `value` argument.